# Prove $0 \leq \frac{b-a}{1-ab} \leq 1$ if $ 0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Prove  that $0 \leq \frac{b-a}{1-ab} \leq 1$  if $ 0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$

It is a pretty easy exersice. I´m starting learning inequalities and  I cant find how prove it.

I want prove that $0 \leq \frac{b-a}{1-ab}$

For it I say that $b-a  \geq 0$ since $a \leq b$, in addition $1-ab$ cannot be zero. it is $a \neq b^{-1}$
then $1-ab<1$ since $1<ab+1$ $a =b \neq 0$ (otherwise $a=b=0$ implies $ 0 \leq\frac{b-a}{1-ab}$)
therefore $\frac{b-a}{1-ab} \geq 0$

Now I want prove that $\frac{b-a}{1-ab} \leq 1$
for this I tryed use the absolute value to the expression, but I fail.
Too try use a triangle inequality, but too fail.
Any hint or advice was very helpful, if someone can tell or explain  how to solve this kind of problems in math was very helpful, because I´m not good for think in tricks for the inequality problems.

Comment: What if $a=b=1$? In that case $1-ab=0$.

Comment: Is not posible since $a=b^{-1}$

Comment: and $1=1^{-1}$ which I deduce that is not possible because the quotient are not defined

Comment: But why $a$ cannot be $b^{-1}$? I don't understand that part of your solution. I mean, $(1,1)$ is a perfectly valid pair of numbers $(a,b)$ such that $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$, isn't?

Comment: I think the OP is saying that $1-ab \neq 0 \implies 1 \neq ab \implies \frac{1}{a} \neq b \implies a \neq b^{-1}$. But it would appear that $(a,b)=(1,1)$ is allowed.

Comment: Guessing the inequality between $a$ and $b$ was meant to be strict...

Comment: I Think the problem would say $0<a<b \leq 1$, but I don´t sure about this statement

Comment: One method could be to solve in reverse order i.e $$\frac{b-a}{1-ab} \leq 1$$ implies $$(a+1)(b-1)\leq0$$ and which is true for given range of a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just rearrange the right part of the inequality (excluding $ab=1$):

$$\frac{b-a}{1-ab} \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow b-a\leq 1-ab \Leftrightarrow b(1+a)\leq 1+a$$
which is obviously true under the given conditions.

Comment: What about this part we can say some of $ab=1$?

Comment: @JuanT Then the expression $\frac{b-a}{1-ab}$ is not defined, since the denominator is $0$. So, any inequality including a not defined expression does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem says $a<b$ then we are only left to prove $\dfrac{b-a}{1-ab}<1$
or
$$ 1-\dfrac{b-a}{1-ab} = \dfrac{1-ab+a-b}{1-ab} = \dfrac{(1+a)(1-b)}{1-ab} $$
And we are done

Answer (score 1):

$$ 1+a = 1+a $$
$$ \Rightarrow b(1+a) \le 1+a $$
$$ \Rightarrow b+ab \le 1+a $$
$$ \Rightarrow b-a \le 1-ab $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{b-a}{1-ab} \le 1 $$

Comment: In the part $b(1+a) \leq 1+a$ is because $a,b$ are numbers between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: It's because $0 \le b \le 1$, so either it remains equal ($b = 1$), or the left hand side is less ($b<1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot,now make sense for me

Comment: You’re very welcome!